# need jquery slide show for div contents

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I need a slideshow like this [website](http://www.zbiddy.com/).

as you can see , in the top of the page is a slide show . I just need a slideshow that change the content of each slide .

I've made my content for each slide and just need a script that change these content .IVe searched alot but all I have found is for image slide shows . I need a slideshow that change the "div" content .

I need your help very much 
Thanks

---

Thanks buddy for your rely but I don't know how to use it for div's content . All of them have been used images . I want to user div instead of img es .

any idea ?
 Thanks